# Anyone know of a good "cookbook" for smartGWT?

Tags: reference, smartgwt

I've done UI dev before, but not SmartGWT.  Wanted to know if there is any such "cookbook" of best practices and "how-to's" - outside of the ShowCase that any of you would strongly recommend.

Thanks!

Alexx

Answer (score 0):

The QuickStart Guide first: http://www.smartclient.com/releases/SmartGWT_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf

Definitely read cover to cover.

Then the public wiki has stuff for specific scenarios (eg how to set up JBoss with SmartGWT Messaging): wiki.smartclient.com